# Safari does not reopen page after Facebook authentication on iPhone

Tags: web, facebook-javascript-sdk, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I'm working on a responsive website that require the user to authenticate with Facebook.
I've set up the Facebook JS SDK, and the login and login-success callback. The setup I have works great on desktop, but on iPhone (seems to work on iPad!) I'm having an issue I am yet to resolve.

When tapping the Login button, the user is brought to a new tab that asks the user to log in. After the user has entered his/her credentials, the tab is closed, but Safari does not reopen my page. Instead, Safari sits in the "tab selection" screen with my page highlighted. The user has to explicitly re-open my page by tapping the tab. When tapping the tab, it doesn't seem to fire the *authResponseChange* consistently.

Please note that if I make sure that Safari on iPhone has no tabs open except my page, then I am automatically directed back to it (as expected by the Safari app's design) and the site functions correctly.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxx',
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true
      });                      
    });      
  });

  $("#login_button").bind("vclick", function() {
    // Require explicit login
    FB.Event.subscribe("auth.authResponseChange", function(response) {
      if (response.status === "connected") {
        // Perform API calls and display more of the page ...
        // $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=")
        // FB.api("/me/friends", function(data) {});
      }
    });                
    FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'email,friends_birthday,friends_hometown'});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Added a note that this seems to work fine on iPad. I opened some tabs on the iPad, then logged in, I was then brought back to my page. I also attempted on two other iPhone devices, and they all act the same way -- i.e. they do not automatically reopen the page after auth.